# how to generate a C# delegate, methods etc. based on a delegate definition with VS2013?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-generation, code-snippets

I have an interop-class and it's really cumbersome to add functionality to it, because it involves so many lines. Let's say I need to have method to get id by id i gotta do following:

```
public class MyInterop
{
    public class WCFDTypes
    {
        //....
        public delegate int GetInt_Delegate(int id);
        //...
    }

    public class DTypes
    {
        //....
        public delegate int DotNetInterface_GetInt_Delegate(int id);
        //...
    }

    public WCFDTypes.GetInt_Delegate GetInt;

    //...

    private DTypes.DotNetInterface_GetPlotLabel_Delegate Nat_GetInt;

    //...

    public MyInterop(string moduleName)
    {
        DelegateBuilder builder = new DelegateBuilder(moduleName);

        //...
        Nat_GetInt = Build<DTypes.DotNetInterface_GetInt_Delegate>(builder);        

        //..
    }

    //...

    GetInt = (int id) =>
    {
        return NatGetInt(id);
    }


    public MyInterop(string moduleName)
    {
        //...
        Nat_GetInt = Build<DTypes.DotNetInterface_GetInt_Delegate>(builder);        

        //..
    }


    public MyInterop(MyApplication, string address)
    {


        //...
        GetInt = client.GetInt;        

        //..
    }
 }
```

Explaining this is beyond the scope of this question. I would just like to know how to generate something, even without return types or parameters just non-variable parts (of course based on fucntionality name like GetInt) to correct places (to both inner classes, 2 method declarations and to 2 constructors).

I was looking into snippets, but examples I found were very basic.

Comment: It is certainly the worst possible way to do this.  Why you cannot use [DllImport] or a C++/CLI wrapper is completely unclear.

Comment: this is not my code. as i said, it's beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: plus it uses DllImport from native dll. also works with WCF for external plugins.

Comment: please see the tags and the text of this question. I knew I should've made some totally different example to ask this question which is about code generation / snippets.

Comment: Maby will this documentaion help you: [Visual Studio snippets](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/visual-studio/4229/visual-studio-snippets#t=201607311158002761603)

Answer (score 1):

You can read the delegate definition from an assembly using classes in System.Reflection.

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyFile); // path to file
Type[] types = asm.GetTypes();
```

[Here](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2010/03/how-to-tell-if-type-is-delegate.html) it is suggested you can recognize delegate types with a method like:

```
public bool IsDelegate(Type type)
{
return type.IsSubClassOf(typeof(Delegate)) || type==typeof(Delegate);
}
```

Or use GetType(string) to load a type whose name you know.

And [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate(v=vs.110).aspx) Microsoft notes (emphasis mine):

> **The common language runtime provides an Invoke method for each delegate type, with the same signature as the delegate**. You do not have to call this method explicitly from C#, Visual Basic, or Visual C++, because the compilers call it automatically. **The Invoke method is useful in reflection when you want to find the signature of the delegate type**.

So use something like this to get a MethodInfo that tells you the param and return type of the delegate:

```
MethodInfo methodInfo =  delegateType.GetMethod("Invoke");
```

Knowing these I expect you can now generate what you need.  It's possible to generate a method at runtime.  See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ffc3x75(v=vs.110).aspx) or search for "Emitting Dynamic Methods and Assemblies".

But you could instead write source code (like your snippet) to a file for later compilation, and if you wish you can automate the compilation with System.CodeDom.Compiler, for example:

```
CodeDomProvider provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CS"); // source language

CompilerParameters compParams = new CompilerParameters();
compParams.IncludeDebugInformation  = true;
foreach (string refAsm in referencedAssemblies) {
    compParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(refAsm);
}
// etc

CompilerResults res = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compParams, codeSource);

if (res.Errors.Count > 0) {
    // display & throw
}
```

Note `codeSource` here is not the path to a source file, but one or more strings containing the actual source code.  So you could even generate and compile the source without the intermediate step of writing it to a file.